# Show instructions on how to use an app on Android

Tags: android, animation

How do you show the user, how to use the app. Is there a tool or something which allows the user to learn how to use it, like a tutorial.

Or what would you do?

By the way, in my app, the user just needs to understand which button needs to be clicked. Basically, he must pick the correct button according to the background color.

Comment: *Is there a tool or something wich allows the user to learn how to use it, like a tutorial.* - Requests to find or recommend an off site resource are off topic. Beyond that, the rest of the question is too broad: there's too many possible answers and any good answer that demonstrates how to do it would be too long.

Comment: You might want to use a ShowCaseView or some similar library. Or else, do like me and use a WebView in a Fragment and explain the usage by using HTML files. Or... well, there's so many ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show or introduce your app to the user is called as show casing your app/views(we can say aka tutorial).

You can make your own showcasing animations but there are some libraries for that purpose

[ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

[spotlight](https://github.com/wooplr/Spotlight)(my favourite one)

You can easily implement that by reading some more stuff about showcasing app or views

Comment: Thank you very much for your usefull anwer. I will have a look at showcase especially spotlight seems nice.

Comment: ;) happy coding!!